# ASP.net C# Multiple Documents on One Response Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

I have this code

```
private void writeReport(IReport report, string reportName)
{
    string reportString = report.makeReport();
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] encodedReport = encoding.GetBytes(reportString);
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ reportName +".txt");
    Response.OutputStream.Write(encodedReport, 0, encodedReport.Length);
    Response.End();
}
```

but I have 3 documents that I need to send to the client.  I'd rather not have to make the user click 3 buttons to get them the 3 txt files.  Is there a way to send all 3 on one reponse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, multipart attachments for download (like as in email) aren't supported for security reasons. It's called a "drive-by download."

Note that Gmail handles this by dynamically zipping up the files. You should too. http://forums.asp.net/t/1240811.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This can be done according to the article "Download multiple files in one http request" on [motobit.com](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_multiple-files-one-request/).

However it's not how HTTP was designed and following those steps may break at any time depending on client and server configuration.